# Cocoapods Spec Access & Ownership Issue

Tags: svg, cocoapods, podspec

For some reason my Cocoapods badge and access is failing to show version and platform.

SwiftyVIPER: [image: CocoaPods Version]

My pod shows up properly: https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftyVIPER

However, my pod account shows no pods: https://cocoapods.org/owners/8966

---

These work:

https://trunk.cocoapods.org/api/v1/pods/Alamofire

https://trunk.cocoapods.org/api/v1/pods/SwiftyVIPER

---

This works: https://trunk.cocoapods.org/api/v1/pods/Alamofire/specs/latest

This doesn't https://trunk.cocoapods.org/api/v1/pods/SwiftyVIPER/specs/latest

---

-----------------  **EDIT**  -----------------

Now, it seems that other pods are failing as well, for example

Alamofire: [image: CocoaPods Version]

And this no longer works: https://trunk.cocoapods.org/api/v1/pods/Alamofire/specs/latest

Comment: I am having the exact same problem, but didn't get the idea to check the api so far. I didn't find a solution, but at least by seeing your question I got the idea to check that api link, so thank you!

Comment: As a small update: This has been reported in an [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6184) at Cocoapods and it might have to do with the sharding of the specs repo. Looks like it's a bug that will eventually be fixed, so we just have to wait. :)

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by the Cocoapods team. Everything seems to be working correctly now.